# Chrome not displaying text until I interact with console

Tags: html, google-chrome

The site in question is thegreengoddessboutique.com

On the site in Chrome, text is not displaying on first load (or after ctrl 5).

If I open the console with inspect element, and interact with html tab at all though, the text displays.

The other browsers have no issues and I cannot think of any javascript that would be causing this issue.

Does anybody have a hint as to what the trouble could be?

Comment: google chrome extensions

Comment: Ok found the problem. @font-face had two url: lines. What is probably happening is, console consolidates the css, which would combine the separate lines into a single one.

Comment: Combining the two url values under a single entry fixed the issue in Chrome. The other browsers never had a problem so most likely they corrected the issue for me.